# How to order queries execution in SQL script so that they are executed in the right order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have three tables:

| Table | References |
| --- | --- |
| A | - |
| B | A |
| C | B |

and I have created a SQL DDL script with these tables' definitions:

`script.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE C(...REFERENCES B...)
CREATE TABLE A(...)
CREATE TABLE B(...REFERENCES A...)
```

**IMPORTANT:** The order of definitions in the script can be random!

Is there are way/tool that would take the script as input and return another SQL script with sorted DDL queries?

Example:

Input `scriptInput.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE B(...REFERENCES A...)   
CREATE TABLE A(...)
CREATE TABLE C(...REFERENCES B...)
```

Output - `scriptOutput.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE A(...)
CREATE TABLE B(...REFERENCES A...) 
CREATE TABLE C(...REFERENCES B...)
```

Comment: Your database project should already have the definitions in an order that means that objects that rely on others are created after, automagically.

Comment: 'The order of definitions in the script can be random' - How so?

Comment: Because I iterate over C# custom types and generate DDL. My current implementation doesn't put the types in a tree (I excluded cyclical graphs) and doesn't  iterate from leafs to root - the order is set by the name of the type so it can be random.

Comment: I guess you should sort it out on the C# side: generate them using a recursive depth-first algorithm. T-SQL is *really* not the place for this kind of string manipulation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical solution is to decouple the table creation from the constraint creation. For example, your script could look like:

```
CREATE TABLE C(...);
CREATE TABLE A(...);
CREATE TABLE B(...);

alter table c add constraint fk1 foreign key (x) references b (y);
alter table b add constraint fk2 foreign key (z) references a (w);
```

This is how production-grade scripts are typically created. This is fool proof since a different person (role DBA) will execute the script in production, and will execute the script without trying to improve it. In case of success (or error) the DBA will provide the execution log back to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that use the super instruction CREATE SCHEMA.
Of course you need to use a specific schema to do that. Not the ugly dbo schema. Example :

```
CREATE SCHEMA SCH_TEST
CREATE TABLE B(PK_B INT PRIMARY KEY, FK_A INT REFERENCES A (PK_A))   
CREATE TABLE A(PK_A INT PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE C(PK_C INT PRIMARY KEY, FK_B INT REFERENCES B (PK_B))
;
```

That's all !

It comes from Standard ISO SQL language...

Comment: That solves my problem partially. What if I wanted to add new tables to the existing schema?

Comment: No, that solve exactly your question.... But probably your question was incomplete !

Comment: Well, you're right!